# Multi level dropdown menu Angular + bootstrap project

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I want to implement the multi level drop down using typescript.
As I went through the bootstrap css framework, I did not find the required multi-level dropdown

[image: Dropdown]

How to create the multi-level dropdown in the angular project using html , css & typescript (I don,t want to use the jQuery)

this is a single level drop-down using bootstrap

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239427/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-a-multi-level-dropdown-menu-with-angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use this material Module https://plugins.codershood.info/#/plugins/ngmm-plugin

And Please do not use native java script in your angular project directly.